# z-index not work on pseudo element in relation to following element

Tags: css, z-index, pseudo-element

I am trying to make an absolute positioned psuedo element appear underneath the following element (not the parent). However, changing the z-index to negative does nothing.

Here is the js [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwybe731/):

```css
#containerA {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
}

#containerB {
  z-index: 100;
}

.quote-marks {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 15em;
  color: yellow;
  background-color: red;
}

.left-quote-marks::before {
  content: "\201C";
}

.authors {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section id="containerA">
  <span class="left-quote-marks quote-marks"></span>

  <div id="quote">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."


  </div>

  <span class="right-quote-marks quote-marks"></span>

</section>

<section id="containerB">
  <div class="authors"> Author </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Changing the `z-index` of `.quote-marks` to `-1` correctly positions your quotation marks behind the text. Is this not what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#quote {
 z-index: 2;
 position: relative;
}
```

Just add z-index with position: relative to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `position: relative` to `#containerB` as well to make the `z-index` take effects.

```css
#containerA {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 4;
}
#containerB {
 /* Added*/
 position: relative;
 z-index: 100;
}

.quote-marks {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 font-size: 15em;
 color: yellow;
 background-color: red;
}
.left-quote-marks::before {
 content: '\201C';
}

.authors {
 cursor: pointer;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section id="containerA">
 <span class="left-quote-marks quote-marks"></span>

 <div id="quote">
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
 </div>

 <span class="right-quote-marks quote-marks"></span>
</section>

<section id="containerB">
 <div class="authors">Author</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#containerA{
 position:relative;
 z-index:4;
}

#containerB{
 z-index:100;
}

.quote-marks{
 position:absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 15em;
  color: yellow;
  background-color:red;
}

.left-quote-marks::before{
 content: "\201C";
}

.authors{
  cursor:pointer;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.quote {
 z-index: 1;
}

.quote-marks {
 z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<section id="containerA">
  <span class="left-quote-marks quote-marks"></span>

  <div id="quote">
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."


  </div>

  <span class="right-quote-marks quote-marks"></span>

</section>

<section id="containerB">
  <div class="authors"> Author </div>
</section>
```

Give negative `z-index` to the div that you want to put behind and positive to the one that you wanted to show. Hope it'd help

Answer (score 0):

z-layers are most effective when all of the `absolute` tags and pseudo-elements are siblings inside a `relative` parent. In order to show any tag that has a negative `z-index` value you must remove or decrease the opacity of the background of any overlapping element with a higher `z-index`. BTW I used semantic tags (a div being the exception), not only does it look better -- it helps in readability as well.

```css
:root {
  font: 700 3vw/1.5 Raleway
}

article {
  position: relative;
  padding: 25% 0;
}

blockquote {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: oblique;
  color: #000;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  z-index: -1;
  color: yellow;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.4;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 3rem 2rem 1rem;
}

.left::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15%;
  left: -10%;
  font-size: 12rem;
  content: "\201C";
  vertical-align: top;
}

cite {
  float: right;
  margin: -1rem 1rem 0 0
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<article>
  <div class='left'></div>
  <blockquote>
<p><q>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</q></p>
    <cite>Author, <b>Work</b></cite>
  </blockquote>
</article>
```